# Insert data received from response body using spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Need your help with the below problem statement.
currently I am working on a project build in spring boot, where I am making an API call and I need to insert the data received from response body.
Example of  response body as follow

String responseBody:

```
{
  "totalNumberOfElements": 436,
  "valuationCurrencyExchangeRates": [
    {
      "baseCurrency": "USD",
      "quoteCurrency": "AUD",
      "bidRate": 32
    },
    {
      "baseCurrency": "USD",
      "quoteCurrency": "CAD",
      "bidRate": 1
    },
    {
      "baseCurrency": "USD",
      "quoteCurrency": "CHF",
      "bidRate": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

From the above mentioned responseBody ,I need to insert the records for valuationCurrencyExchangeRates.
I need to create a table with 3 columns(baseCurrency,quoteCurrency,bidRate) which will have 3 records as mentioned above.
Your help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What did you try so far? What is not working?

Comment: I am wondering the same thing as Andy. Do you have a RestTemplate setup? Do you have issues with consuming the Rest data? And how do you want to present it in a table (basic JSP for example)? In case you only tried the API call and have not setup anything in your Spring Boot application so far, I would recommend researching Consuming a Rest API with Spring Boot, the internet is full of great tutorials and examples.

Comment: may be my question was little abstract. So far i have finished with connecting with external api  and inserted the response body as whole in one of  the table. Here I am seeking help to find a best possible way to filter the data which i have received as the response and insert in more structured way.